# Cosmos: Update to Swift 4 reveals new issue: The following binaries use incompatible versions of Swift

Tags: swift4

After I updated my App to Swift 4 I get this error message:
error: **The following binaries use incompatible versions of Swift:**
/Users/Konrad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExploreYourCity-btthjezgywzvnmduiurzwgwzrven/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cosmos/Cosmos.framework/Cosmos
/Users/Konrad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExploreYourCity-btthjezgywzvnmduiurzwgwzrven/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExploreYourCity.app/ExploreYourCity
I can not find a solution to this misstake. Whats wrong?

Library setup method: CocoaPods
Version of the library. Example: 12.0.1.
Xcode version. Example:9.0.1.
OS version. Example: iOS 11.0.
*Swift Version: Swift 4.0.

Answer (score -1):

1) Select Project in Project Navigator.
2) Go to General Tab.
3) Remove everything under Embedded Binaries.
4) Remove everything under Linked Frameworks and Libraries except Pods_*.framework
5) Clean, Build and Run.